# create a variance column in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

hi im using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio,

I have the below query which is doing as intended,

```
Select    
    EU.[Store No]
   ,EU.[Store Name]
   ,sum(case when SA.Fiscalyear = 2017 and EU.Country = 'UK' then SA.Salesexvat/SA.ExchangeRateEuro end ) AS '2017 UK'    
   ,sum(case when SA.Fiscalyear = 2016 and EU.Country = 'UK' then SA.Salesexvat/SA.ExchangeRateEuro end ) AS '2016 UK'
From 
    dbo.EUACTIVESTORES EU    
Join
    EUUKSQL01.dashboard.dbo.SalesAggregateWeek SA On SA.BranchNo = EU.[Store No]
where EU.[Upload Type]='Main' and SA.fiscalweek <=19    
group by EU.[Store No], EU.[Store Name]
order by EU.[Store No]
```

I need to create a new column that will show the result of:
(2017 UK / 2016 UK)- 1

For each StoreNo, to show variance between the two years,

Any suggestions ?

Comment: " I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" Eh? So what's that got to do with MySQL?

Comment: not too sure whats what with it all at the moment quite new, appologies if its incorrect

Comment: @peterhinton being new is not really an excuse not knowing what product you are using. That's relatively simple to find out. By mistagging the question, you may get answers that will not be usable for you and will annoy those, who would like to help you. In this particular case the sql code helped me to determine which of the 2 products you use and could fix the question, but going forward it would be nice if you determined this yourself **before** asking any questions.

Comment: Taken note guys, Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat the 2 sums in a calculated field to achieve the expected outcome:

```
Select    
    EU.[Store No]
   ,EU.[Store Name]
   ,sum(case when SA.Fiscalyear = 2017 and EU.Country = 'UK' then SA.Salesexvat/SA.ExchangeRateEuro end ) AS '2017 UK'    
   ,sum(case when SA.Fiscalyear = 2016 and EU.Country = 'UK' then SA.Salesexvat/SA.ExchangeRateEuro end ) AS '2016 UK'
   ,sum(case when SA.Fiscalyear = 2017 and EU.Country = 'UK' then SA.Salesexvat/SA.ExchangeRateEuro end ) / sum(case when SA.Fiscalyear = 2016 and EU.Country = 'UK' then SA.Salesexvat/SA.ExchangeRateEuro end ) - 1 as variance
From 
    dbo.EUACTIVESTORES EU    
Join
    EUUKSQL01.dashboard.dbo.SalesAggregateWeek SA On SA.BranchNo = EU.[Store No]
where EU.[Upload Type]='Main' and SA.fiscalweek <=19    
group by EU.[Store No], EU.[Store Name]
order by EU.[Store No]
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the code inside `CTE` and do the calc in CTE `select` query. This makes the query more readable.

```
;With CTE As
(
Select    
    EU.[Store No]
   ,EU.[Store Name]
   ,sum(case when SA.Fiscalyear = 2017 and EU.Country = 'UK' then SA.Salesexvat/NULLIF(SA.ExchangeRateEuro,0) end ) AS '2017 UK'    
   ,sum(case when SA.Fiscalyear = 2016 and EU.Country = 'UK' then SA.Salesexvat/NULLIF(SA.ExchangeRateEuro,0) end ) AS '2016 UK'
From 
    dbo.EUACTIVESTORES EU    
Join
    EUUKSQL01.dashboard.dbo.SalesAggregateWeek SA On SA.BranchNo = EU.[Store No]
where EU.[Upload Type]='Main' and SA.fiscalweek <=19    
group by EU.[Store No], EU.[Store Name]
)
Select *,([2017 UK] / NULLIF([2016 UK],0))- 1
order by [Store No]
```

**Note :** Used `NULLIF` function in denominator to avoid *divided by zero* error

Comment: think I understand the NULLIF you have put in, In my case the EU.[Upload Type]='Main' will rule out any stores that do not have 2016 sales, but thanks for the input its all really useful while I'm just starting out in SQL

Comment: @peterhinton - Good to know :D

Comment: @peterhinton - You don't know what data will come in future. It is always better to write code that will handle exceptions

Comment: totally agree and I will take this on board, its better to get into good habits now,

Answer (score 0):

Fastest solution:

```
SELECT *, ([2017 UK]/[2016 UK])-1 as [index]
FROM (
Select    
    EU.[Store No]
   ,EU.[Store Name]
   ,sum(case when SA.Fiscalyear = 2017 and EU.Country = 'UK' then SA.Salesexvat/SA.ExchangeRateEuro end ) AS '2017 UK'    
   ,sum(case when SA.Fiscalyear = 2016 and EU.Country = 'UK' then SA.Salesexvat/SA.ExchangeRateEuro end ) AS '2016 UK'
From 
    dbo.EUACTIVESTORES EU    
Join
    EUUKSQL01.dashboard.dbo.SalesAggregateWeek SA On SA.BranchNo = EU.[Store No]
where EU.[Upload Type]='Main' and SA.fiscalweek <=19    
group by EU.[Store No], EU.[Store Name]
)
order by [Store No]
```